# Unable to Upgrade from 13.04 to 13.10

Tags: upgrade, update-manager

Following is what I get as error

```
Error during update 

A problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of 
network problem, please check your network connection and retry. 

W:Failed to fetch 
http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-backports/main/source/Sources 
404 Not Found 
, W:Failed to fetch 
http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-backports/restricted/source/Sources 
404 Not Found 
, W:Failed to fetch 
http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-backports/universe/source/Sources 
404 Not Found 
, W:Failed to fetch 
http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-backports/multiverse/source/Sources 
404 Not Found 
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or 
old ones used instead. 


Restoring original system state
```

I am using command line `do-release-upgrade`

I have changed my dns to google public dns and verified that using `nslookup` and `host -v`

I could not find `bg.archive.ubuntu.com` in any of the source list files.

In another tab I have `ping google` running just to verify that network is not down. Network has no issues.

Comment: Are you connected via wireless? I've had some similar issues while upgrading. Try wired connection (ethernet).

Comment: Honestly, connecting wired is pain, I will rather stick to 13.04 :) till I find this problem's solution

Comment: its not recommended to install 13.10 since its support is withdrawn and you will not get system updates. better install 14.04 which much stable than 13.10

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with old distros being archived. I found a previous question that talks about it

[How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

along with a ubuntu page [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades/)

Hope this helps.

Edit: The steps I had to take turned out to be a tad different than what was suggested. I changed the `bg.archive.ubuntu.com` found in `/etc/apt/source.list.d/precise.list` to `old-releases.ubuntu.com` and things worked like a charm.

Comment: The OP stated "from 13.04", but has "natty-backports" ... so you might have a point here.

Answer (score 0):

I would try installing the upgrade from a DVD or USB flash drive. It might work, and I think there is an option on the USB or DVD to upgrade your current Ubuntu installation so you lose no files. Of course, I recommend backup first! If that doesn't work, I would try a full re-installation of Ubuntu which would reformat your old installation of Ubuntu and reinstall from scratch. Then just restore all your files from a backup that you created, if you have important files on it. Good luck!